# Redshift - First and Last day of month in a Table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

The below code work when getting the first day of the month in Redshift:

```
SELECT 
    date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '1 month' as start_date;
```

However when I try to add the output of the Select statement to a Table I get an error:

```
CREATE TABLE test AS
   SELECT 
       date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '1 month' as start_date;
```

ERROR:  Interval values with month or year parts are not supported

How can I now calculate the start_date of the previous month and store that value in a table?
I have tried subtracting days instead of a month but the number of days to subtract differ depending on the month in questions so it is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `add_months()`work?

```
SELECT add_months(date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE), -1) as start_date;
```